# escape drive path C# To MySQL

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

i'm using MySQL With .Net(C#), and i want to store drive path in DB 
example: "D:\" OR "\NetworkDrive", and i use

```
 MySqlCommand objCommand = new MySqlCommand(strSql, Connection);
 objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 objCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paramName","D:\\");
 objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

it return error Like this "**Unhandled type encountered**"
I try to escape the path like this

```
 objCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paramName","D:\\\\");
 objCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paramName",@"D:\\");
 objCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("paramName","D:\\");
```

also it's not working.

Comment: What is the datatype of paramName column?

Comment: Can you run the query with any string, like `"test"`, or this problem occurs only with strings containing paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem using MS-SQL, where I wanted to put a single quote into a query. Use a MYSQL escape character, the list of which are here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-syntax.html

Basically if you know for a fact one of those problem characters are going to be in your query, escape them out with .replace before you build your query.

Comment: my problem is not to store a single quota , may problem is to store drive path(Fixed or network) :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySql, you typically use the ? for parameter identifiers, try:

```
objCommand.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("?paramName",@"D:\");
```

Comment: this is not my question but i try to send @"D:\" and its not working!